# How to create a MSI for a database by NANT script

Tags: database, for-loop, windows-installer

I have some batch files which will call sql scripts internally.These sql scripts will create the database.Here what is my task is to create a msi which will accept username,password,etc and if user credientials are correct then that user interface should allow user to run that batch fiels.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very customized installer, so you need a setup authoring tool. If you want something free you can try WiX.